# Sending Facebook Message Without Using Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk

Since I don't have Facebook App installed, I am not able to use the code below because, as I understand, FacebookDialog needs Facebook App. Is there any way to open this MessageDialog feature in the web browser without using Facebook App?

```
FacebookDialog fd = new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(Activity.this)
                .setApplicationName("xxx")
                .setName("xxxx")
                .setLink("xxx")
                .build();

uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(fd.present());
```

Second try with WebDialog but no luck:

```
new WebDialog.Builder(context, 
        Session.getActiveSession(), 
        "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=742298472475427&link=http%3A//www.example.com&redirect_uri=http%3A//www.example2.com", 
        null)
    .build()
    .show();
```

When I call this, Facebook loads something and then gives the following error:

`The page you requested was not found.`

Comment: You could use the web message dialog

Comment: @WizKid: Do you have any examples or external links? Though I could not find any information on the Internet.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: @WizKid, yes I know that page but please notice that: `This dialog can be used with the JavaScript SDK and by performing a full redirect to a URL. It is not supported on mobile devices.`

Comment: Then there is no way